# What is the profinite completion of a free abelian group of infinite rank?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

By definition, profinite completion of a group $G$ is $\widehat{G}=\varprojlim_N G/N$ where $N$ runs through every subgroup of finite index in $G$.
Let $M=\bigoplus_{n\ge1} \Bbb{Z}$ be a free abelian group of countably infinite rank.

$1$. What is $\widehat{M}$?

My guess is  $\widehat{M}=\prod_{n\ge1}\Bbb{\widehat{Z}}$. 
Am I right? How can I prove?

$2$. More generally, what is $\widehat{\oplus_{n\ge1}{ C_n}}$ where $C_n$ is cyclic group? Is it ${\prod_{n\ge1}{\widehat{ C_n}}}$?

Similarly what is pro-$p$-completions?

My questioins are originated from the profinite completion of $\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$, the multiplicative group of the rational number field.

It is known that $\Bbb{Q}^{\times}\cong {\{\pm1\}}\times \bigoplus_{n\ge1} \Bbb{Z} $

Comment: I'm not sure what $\widehat{M}$ is, but unlike $\prod_{n \ge 1}\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, it is not countably based.  $M$ has uncountably many subgroups of finite index: consider the group of homomorphisms from $\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to the circle group.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Pontryagin dual of a direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in I}G_i$ is always isomorphic (isomorphism of topological abelian groups) to the product of the respective duals, as long as all the $G_i$'s and the direct sum are all considered with the discrete topology. So M is going to be naturally identified with $\prod_{i \in I} \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. As for the proof of my first statement, see the article on direct sums of modules on wikipedia. There it is explained how a natural algebraic isomorphism is obtained. However, it's not too hard to show that it is also a homeomorphism.